# WinForms application design - moving documents from SQL Server to file storage

Tags: sql-server, winforms

I have a standard WinForms application that connects to a SQL Server.  The application allows users to upload documents which are currently stored in the database, in a table using an image column.

I need to change this approach so the documents are stored as files and a link to the file is stored in the database table.

Using the current approach - when the user uploads a document they are shielded from how this is stored, as they have a connection to the database they do not need to know anything about where the files are stored, no special directory permissions etc are required.  If I set up a network share for the documents I want to avoid any IT issues such as the users having to have access to this directory to upload to or access existing documents.

What are the options available to do this?  I thought of having a temporary database where the documents are uploaded to in the same way as the current approach and then a process running on the server to save these to the file store.  This database could then be deleted and recreated to reclaim any space.  Are there any better approaches?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**  There is no web server element to my application so I do not think a WCF service is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to get the files out of the database in the first place?

How about still saving them in SQL Server, but using a [`FILESTREAM` column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx) instead of `IMAGE`?

Quote from the link:

> FILESTREAM enables SQL Server-based applications to store unstructured
>   data, such as documents and images, on the file system. Applications
>   can leverage the rich streaming APIs and performance of the file
>   system and at the same time maintain transactional consistency between
>   the unstructured data and corresponding structured data.
>
> FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an NTFS file
>   system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data as
>   files on the file system. Transact-SQL statements can insert, update,
>   query, search, and back up FILESTREAM data. Win32 file system
>   interfaces provide streaming access to the data.
>
> FILESTREAM uses the NT system cache for caching file data. This helps
>   reduce any effect that FILESTREAM data might have on Database Engine
>   performance. The SQL Server buffer pool is not used; therefore, this
>   memory is available for query processing.

So you would get the best out of both worlds:
The files would be stored as files on the hard disk (probabl faster compared to storing them in the database), but you don't have to care about file shares, permissions etc.

Note that you need at least SQL Server 2008 to use `FILESTREAM`.

Comment: Oh yeah, filestream :D almost forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how I implemented this task.  I wrote a WCF service which is used to send archived files.  So, if I were you, I would create such a service which should be able to save  files and send them back.  This is easy and you also must be sure that the user under which context the WCF service works has permission to read write files.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have your application pass the object to a procedure (CLR maybe) in the database which then writes the data out to the location of your choosing without storing the file contents. That way you still have a layer of abstraction between the file store and the application but you don't need to have a process which cleans up after you.

Alternatively a WCF/web service could be created which the application connects to. A web method could be used to accept the file contents and write them to the correct place, it could return the path to the file or some file identifier.